# thumbs_up Rails gem's "at_least" and "order" methods not doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the thumbs_up gem in Rails to create a voting system. In one of my controllers, I have a model called `Superlative` that `acts_as_voteable`, and I'm trying to filter out the objects with at least one vote.

Based on the [documentation and online resources](http://rubydoc.info/github/brady8/thumbs_up/), this should work:

```
def most_votes
  @most_votes = Superlative.tally(
    { :at_least => 1,
    :limit => 10,
    :order => 'vote_count desc'
  })
end
```

But I get all the records in the Superlative model back, even ones with 0 votes. Also, the ordering doesn't seem to work either. Not matter if I put `desc` or `asc` the ordering is always `desc`.

I Googled everywhere but no one seems to have the same problem.

Here are some relevant app details:

```
Using thumbs_up (0.6.5)
Using rails (3.2.13) 
ruby 1.9.3p429
```

**Update: additional info**
I tried running the above controller code (that's all for that action) in the console, and again, all records were returned, including those with 0 votes.

Also, view code below:

```
- provide(:title, "Best Superlatives")
#superlatives
  %h1.title Superlatives (Most Votes)
  %table.table.table-hover
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Name
        %th Most Likely ...
        %th Votes
        %th Vote!
    %tbody
      = render @most_votes
%br/
```

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work it could be that you are overwriting the content of the variable @most_votes at some point before you draw it on your views.

Try to go into the rails console by running

```
bundle exec script/rails console
```

Once you are in the console try to run:

```
@most_votes = Superlative.tally(
  { :at_least => 1,
    :limit => 10,
    :order => 'vote_count desc'
  })
```

And now check the content of @most_votes, you should see the votes which has at least 1 vote, with the right order, I'm pretty sure the gems works fine on these queries since I never had any problem with it and its being used by many developers on production environment.

If after doing that you confirm that the gem is working fine, try to update your question with the complete controller code, and the complete view code so we can help to debug the issue.

Comment: Just added additional info -- even in the console, all records are being returned, so I don't think it is a view issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post a sample project/code on github and give me the url? So I can clone it, reproduce it and be able to debug, I cannot find of other way to help you than actually being able to run the code and debug it. It should be a straighforward debug dough.

Comment: git@github.com:philipliou/nehsalumni.git